# How to display a string in client browser console using c#?

Tags: 2010, javascript, client-object-model, client-side-rendering, debugging

Let's assume I have a C# file in my SP2010 application and I want to display a message in the browser console.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
...

public class WhatEver{
    // some code goes here

    string str = "StackExchangeReader"

    Console.log("Hello"); 
    // Console.log(str);  here the code I want to use to display
}
```

It could be in JavaScript or anything else as long as I have access to my variable. The purpose of this is to debug a production environnement application. No Visual Studio or any other solution that implies installing a third part application is allowed.

I've read this article which I found really interesting but the answer given does not work for me especially the [MichaelTaylor3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713782/asp-net-mvc-console-writeline-to-browser)'s answer.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can log to a file or to sharepoint list. I think is more "natural".

Comment: you can use Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerclientscriptblock(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Use the logging feature in SharePoint.. Use can log information into ULS, EventViewer etc.

Comment: ULS uses server stored logs and I have no access to them. Moreover, even if I could get the logs, what am I suppose to do with "the error was in the TwoThousandsLinesMethod" ? The logs aren't specific enough to be used efficiently. It would be great if I just could write my variable value somewhere it is quickly and easily accessible. @jpussacq gave the best answer until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I allways create a log in a SharePoint List. It is easy to filter and subscribe by mail. This is an example of C# to log in SPList:

```
public static void log(SPWeb web, string titulo, string detalle, string criticidad, string modulo, string sitioUrl, string sitioNombre)
{
    SPList listaLog = web.Site.RootWeb.Lists.TryGetList("Log");
    if (listaLog != null)
    {
        web.Site.RootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        SPListItem logItem = listaLog.Items.Add();
        SPFieldUrlValue sitio = new SPFieldUrlValue();
        sitio.Description = sitioNombre;
        sitio.Url = sitioUrl;
        logItem["Sitio"] = sitio;
        logItem["Título"] = titulo;
        logItem["Detalle"] = detalle;
        logItem["Criticidad"] = criticidad;
        logItem["Modulo"] = modulo;
        logItem["Fecha"] = DateTime.Now;
        logItem.Update();
        web.Site.RootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution could be the use of the ULS (Unified Logging Service) by writing the variable content inside the log file whenever it is necessary.

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;    
var i = "variableContent"
SPDiagnosticsService.Local.WriteTrace(0, new SPDiagnosticsCategory("My Category", TraceSeverity.Unexpected, EventSeverity.Error), TraceSeverity.Unexpected, i.toString(), "this parameter should normaly contain exception stack trace");
```

This snippet is normaly use inside a try/catch structure but I don't really need it.